# Permission denied when deleting file with sudo

Tags: permissions, osx, sudo, rm

I have quite a predicament. I have created a binary file `/Library/Application Support/XXX/DaemonLauncher`. When I try to delete it, I get the following:

```
$ sudo rm -f /Library/Application\ Support/XXX/DaemonLauncher 
rm: /Library/Application Support/XXX/DaemonLauncher: Permission denied
```

This seems strange as I am obviously using `sudo` and `root` is the owner of the file, which grants all permissions as can be seen:

```
$ ls -@alO /Library/Application\ Support/XXX/DaemonLauncher
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  - 1 Oct 23 13:32 /Library/Application Support/XXX/DaemonLauncher
```

I have noticed other people seem to get permission errors when trying to delete files with `sudo` if the file is a binary that is currently running, but mine doesn't seem to be:

```
$ ps aux | grep DaemonLauncher
sschilli          6504   0.0  0.0  4268056    820 s005  S+    1:43PM   0:00.00 grep DaemonLauncher
```

I can open the file, modify it, and execute it, but am unable to delete it. What could be causing this?

Comment: @UncleBilly all parent directories have the same permissions: `rwxr-xr-x`/`755`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a recent version of macOS, you will notice that the root filesystem is mounted read-only, which means that no amount of `sudo`-ing would make it possible to delete files on it.

I'm not 100% sure how a current macOS system handles its various filesystems, but the root filesystem is mounted read-only while `/System/Volumes/Data` is overlayed on top of it somehow to provide a layer onto which modifications may be made.